# How do I update a column from a table with data from a another column from this same table?

Tags: sql, sql-update, extract

I have a table "table1" like this:

```
+------+--------------------+
| id   | barcode     | lot  |
+------+-------------+------+
| 0    | ABC-123-456 |      |
| 1    | ABC-123-654 |      |
| 2    | ABC-789-EFG |      |
| 3    | ABC-456-EFG |      |
+------+-------------+------+
```

I have to extract the number in the center of the column "barcode", like with this request :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(barcode, 5, 3) AS ToExtract FROM table1;
```

The result:

```
+-----------+
| ToExtract |
+-----------+
| 123       |
| 123       |
| 789       |
| 456       |
+-----------+
```

And insert this into the column "lot" .

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow along the lines

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

i.e in your case

```
UPDATE table_name
SET lot = SUBSTR(barcode, 5, 3)
WHERE condition;(if any)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 SET Lot = SUBSTR(barcode, 5, 3) 
-- WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support generated (aka "virtual"/"computed" columns).  This allows you to define a column *as an expression*.  The syntax is something like this:

```
alter table table1 add column lot varchar(3) generated always as (SUBSTR(barcode, 5, 3))
```

Using a generated column has several advantages:

- It is always up-to-date.
- It generally does not occupy any space.
- There is no overhead when creating the table (although there is overhead when querying the table).

I should note that the syntax varies a bit among databases.  Some don't require the type specification.  Some use just `as` instead of `generated always as`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1(id INT,barcode varchar(255),lot varchar(255))
> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (0,'ABC-123-456',NULL),(1,'ABC-123-654',NULL),(2,'ABC-789-EFG',NULL)
>                    ,(3,'ABC-456-EFG',NULL)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE a
> SET a.lot = SUBSTRING(b.barcode, 5, 3)
> FROM Table1 a
> INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.id=b.id
> WHERE a.lot IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> id | barcode     | lot
> -: | :---------- | :--
>  0 | ABC-123-456 | 123
>  1 | ABC-123-654 | 123
>  2 | ABC-789-EFG | 789
>  3 | ABC-456-EFG | 456
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13bf820491e70eecc2b3dab8e89f1811)*